# Один Navigation Drawer Menu на все активити

Tags: java, android

У меня на главной странице имеется Drawer Menu. Не получается подключить меню на другие активити тоесть на SO.com говорят, что нужно наследоваться от главной активити и внизу прописать

```
super.onCreateDrawer()
```

но проблема в том, что на главном активити у меня нету такого метода - это первое.

И второе - AndroidStudio создал 4 разметки для меню и тут:

**drawer_activity_main.xml**

```
.........
<include
    layout="@layout/drawer_app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
.........
```

**drawer_app_bar_main**

```
........
<include layout="@layout/drawer_content_main" />
........
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.drawer_activity_main);
```

Вот тут проблема, потому что в этой разметке расположена главная разметка, и вот если даже другие активити наследуются от главного то что они покажут в контенте?

**И подумав мне кажется что мой подход неправильный, так вот, как правильно реализовать?**

Answer (score 1):

Используйте один `activity` с меню и несколько `fragment` в качестве страниц. По тапу на элемент меню меняйте фрагменты.

[Информация по теме](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

В `Android studio 1.5.1` при добавлении **Navigation Drawer Activity** создается:

1. `Activity` класс.
2. **layout** с `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`(Это ваше меню).
3. **AppBar layout**(Здесь панель приложения и
   `floating action button`).
4. **Content layout** c
   пустым `relative layout` (это контентная часть).

В `activity` есть метод `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, В нем `switch` по элементам меню. Добавляем

```
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PAGE_TAG_MAIN);
            if (f == null) f = new MainFragment();
            f.setRetainInstance(true);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, f, PAGE_TAG_MAIN).commit();
```

где:

`R.id.container`—**id** контентной `view` в `layout` из пункта **4**,

`PAGE_TAG_MAIN` строковая константа `Activity` класса:

```
private static final String PAGE_TAG_MAIN = "main";
```