# Sliding Menu / Navigation Drawer c несколькими активити

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, sliding-menu

Я хотела бы сделать приложение с `Navigation Drawer` с несколькими активностями. Но все примеры приложений, которые я видела, используют `Sliding Menu` / `Navigation Drawer` с одной активностью и несколькими фрагментами. Что наводит меня на мысль, что архитектура с `Navigation Drawer` с несколькими активностями противоречит каким-то правилам...

Можно ли сделать несколько активити и из меню запускать-менять эти активити, вместо смены фрагментов? И если да, была бы очень благодарна за ссылки на примеры создания приложений с такой архитектурой.

P.S. Я видела вопросы [Как правильно построить navigation drawer?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516441/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-navigation-drawer)
и [Один Navigation Drawer Menu на все активити](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498176/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-navigation-drawer-menu-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8), но ответы на них, по-моему, противоречат друг другу...

Comment: А что мешает в каждой активити добавить нав дравер? и потом при открытии просто делать селектнутым текущий айтем

Comment: А почему Вы хотите использовать именно активити, а не фрагменты?

Comment: @post_zeew, процитирую: " потому, что обычно на фрагментах отображают схожую инфу и нет смысла под них активити делать. А вот настройки какие-нить и/или запуск камеры логичнее в другой активити сделать, т.к. это, обычно, к инфе с главной активити слабо относится. Типа идёт разделение по типу контента/действия"

Comment: У меня примерно та же причина

Comment: Основная причина использования фрагментов - не требуется дублировать код дровера в каждой активити (а так и нужно будет делать при нескольких активити), но вы можете создать базовую активити , реализующюю дровер и остальные свои активити  наследовать от нее, это решит данную проблему. Никаких "противопоказаний" к использованию активити вместо фрагментов тут нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли сделать несколько активити и из меню запускать-менять эти активити, вместо смены фрагментов?

Чисто технически, конечно, можно.

В данной ситуации выбор между фрагментами и активити сильно зависит от контекста, и, в общем случае, довольно трудно дать какие-либо рекомендации.

Однако, я считаю, что при выборе между фрагментами и активити, в данной ситуации нужно следовать принципу: если в отображаемом представлении должно быть то же самое боковое меню, то следует использовать фрагменты, в противном случае – активити.

Приведу пример: приложение для какой-либо соц. сети, содержащее следующие представления:

1. Экран со страницей пользователя;
2. Экран с друзьями пользователя;
3. Экран с сообщениями;
4. Экран для редактирования страницы пользователя;
5. Экран настроек приложения.

Вызов всех этих представлений можно сделать из бокового меню, при этом боковое меню следует отобразить только в первых трех случаях. В четвертом и пятом представлениях боковое меню излишне, ибо нет необходимости вернутся из них на какой-то определенный экран. Возвращение на предыдущее представление логичнее сделать либо кнопкой `back`, либо кнопкой, сохраняющей изменения.

В итоге получаем, первые три – фрагменты, остальные два – активити.

И заметьте, на первых трех представлениях, в принципе, содержится **разного** рода информация, однако для их отображения используются фрагменты.